# Visual Studio 2019 Export result from Azure Database failed

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms, visual-studio-loadtest

I am getting the following error while trying to export the loadtest result using Visual Studio 2019 and the result is stored in Azure database.

> SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 40515 Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server
> Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Reference to database and/or server
> name in  is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

FYI, SQL Server 12 is installed on the local machine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqyHn.png)

I am trying to export the load test result from here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65LAs.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. You might want to include actual commands that you are executing. Are you exporting it to an Azure database? Are you specifying the destination/source? Potential [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52313532/bcp-queryout-from-azure-vm-sqlstate-37000-nativeerror-40515-reference-to)

Comment: The load test results database has been moved to Azure SQL database. In Visual Studio 2019, Data Source is pointing to this Azure SQL database and we are trying to export load test results. The machine where Visual Studio is installed is having SQL Server 2012. No commands are being run. Thanks.

Comment: @user14208140 As I understand, the  load test results database is now in Azure SQL database, now you want to export the  database 'load test result' from VS, am I right? And how did you get the error, what have you did? Just from the error message, the error happened when connect to the Azure SQL database.

Comment: @LeonYue, I have updated the question with snapshots, please let know if it is still not clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the load test results database is now in Azure SQL database, now you want to export the database 'load test result' from VS.

Not very clear about how you get the error and what you have did, just from the error message, the error happened when connect to the Azure SQL database.

[image]

As the loadtest result database is in Azure SQL database, Visual Studio Server Explorer doesn't support import/export task.

Please use SSMS as instead:
[image]

Comment: I have added the screenshot from where I try to export the result in Visual Studio, please let me know if it is still not clear.
Thanks.